# jQuery datepicker show events on document ready

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to show events on document ready. How to do that? The following method works but only when I click on date.

```
var Event = function (text, className) {
    this.text = text;
   this.className = className;
};

var events = {};
events[new Date("03/14/2015")] = new Event("Lorem ipsum", "event");

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({

            beforeShowDay: function (date)
            {
                var event = events[date];
                if (event) {
                    return [true, event.className, event.text];
                }
                else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is the `events` array defined?

Comment: Don't worry :) There is
var Event = function (text, className) {
    this.text = text;
   this.className = className;
};

var events = {};
events[new Date("03/14/2015")] = new Event("Valentines Day", "event");

This works but I want to show On Document Ready it's working on selected

Comment: there is 2 events. April 23 and April 25 When I click any date(1 to 30 ). They appears on picker selected. But I want this on Document ready not onclick. beforeShowDay method working like onclick.

Comment: The datepicker values render on click, so it is the expected behavior. Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xeobLrdg/

Comment: Shaunak D. no i dont want this. i want April 23 and April 25 different color or background on document ready